# Кастомный адаптер для ListView из массива без некоторых его элементов

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день!
Есть адаптер для ListView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.category, parent, false);
            }

            Category currentCategory = categoryList.get(position);

            ImageView categoryImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_categoryImg);
            categoryImg.setImageResource(imgid[categoryList.get(position).getCategory() - 1]);

            TextView categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

            //categoryName.setTypeface(lobster);
            categoryName.setText(currentCategory.getCategoryName());

            return itemView;
    }
```

Как исключить при формировании списка ListView строки, где `categoryList.get(position).getCategory() != некольким числам` ?

Comment: самый простой способ, отдавать сформированный список, без лишних элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конструкторе создать копию массива categoryList, из которой исключить ненужные элементы, и строить ListView не из categoryList, а из этой копии.